# Making the animation script more efficient

Tags: jquery, animation, performance

I've written a small animation script, a couple of snowflakes falling down. It all works great, but I'm wondering weather I can make it a bit more efficient, simply because I don't consider myself that much of a good programmer and I'm sure I made some mistakes here or there. Just trying to learn. Thank You in advance!
Here's the link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gxkX/6/light/)

or the script itself:

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
{
     var arr = ["1000", "2000", "3000", "4000"];
     var pause = 0;
    var myDiv = $('div');
    function scroll()
    {
       if (pause == 0)
       {
        myDiv.each(function (index)
        {
            myDiv.eq(index).delay(arr[index]).animate({"margin-top":"150px","opacity":"1"},
           {
            duration:3000,
            queue: true,
               complete: function ()
               {
                   $(this).css({"margin-top":"0","opacity":"0"});
                 pause = 0;
                 scroll();  
               }
           });

        });
    }  


    }
    scroll();
});
```

Comment: [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2gxkX/9/

I make a few tweaks here are there.  Overall your code is good.

- myDiv -> myDivs since it's multiple
- `myDivs.eq(index)` replaced with `$(this)`
- on the chaining I put in new lines to make it more readable
- I replaced `"margin-top"` with `top` since they're absolutely positioned
- `"0"` etc replaced with `0` since jquery knows how to handle numbers
- array removed in favor of a simpler expression
- and I self invoked the function

**EDIT:**
simple version: http://jsfiddle.net/2gxkX/10/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers, @generalhenry I Learned from both of them!

Comment: now that's what I'm calling efficiency - http://jsfiddle.net/2gxkX/10/ Your edit's awesome, thanks a lot. Learned a ton from it, especially the self invoke thing!

Comment: @Skatebail Careful there. The code is compacted but that doesn't mean it's efficient. Keep in mind that the scroll() function as it stands selects all four divs each time it's invoked and each of the four animations makes a subsequent call to scroll(). That's four more callbacks making four more DOM traversals, each invoking four animation calls (i.e. registering 16 animate calls per loop, which you don't see since jQuery cancels the last call). The handler/trigger model only makes one call to its own event handler and needs no DOM traversal: four event handler invocations–nothing more.

Comment: @lthibodeaux Thanks for the heads up, the explanation's great, makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you might bind a custom event and simply recursively call the event at the end of each animation to produce the same effect. It's probably a bit more semantically clean and easier on the JS engine:

```
$("div").each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).bind('snowfall', function() { // bind a custom event
        $(this).animate({
            "top": 150,
            "opacity": 1
        }, 3000, function() { // callback to reset CSS styling and recurse
            $(this).css({
                top: 0,
                opacity: 0
            }).delay((i + 1) * 1000).trigger('snowfall'); // recurse
        })
    }).delay((i + 1) * 1000).trigger('snowfall'); // initial fire
});
```

What happens above is that each element has a "snowfall" event handler bound that causes the animation. At the end of the animation, there is a call back to delay the given amount of time and then trigger a subsequent snowfall event. After the binding is complete, the chosen delay is used, and the first trigger is started to begin the recursive animation.

Hope you find this useful!

Here's a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/88H8t/).

**EDIT:** @generalhenry makes a most excellent point about the array; editing the code to reflect that wise change.

Comment: @Skatebail You'll notice I decided to animate the CSS top attribute over the margin-top attribute. Since we're effectively modifying the element's positioning and your snowflakes already have a position other than "static," I feel this is a better, more reflective attribute choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers, I Learned from both of them!  @lthibodeaux

Comment: I'm a little disappointed. After watching system resources in a few browsers, IE9 seems to be the only one properly garbage collecting the handler/trigger method. In most other browsers, the code actually seems to be piling up a somewhat surprising memory leak. Won't kill anyone's box in a hurry but that's no bueno, no matter what performance tradeoffs might exist.